# Finding spaces OR commas with wildcard search

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, find-and-replace, text-formatting, wildcards

I'm writing some macros that will automate frequent cleanup/text formatting tasks in the bibliographies I edit. For background, these bibliographies often contain citations for chapters from edited volumes AND citations from journals.

I want to automatically find all instances of

`(.” In )(<*>)(, edited)`

as in

> EDITED VOLUME EXAMPLE:
>
> Ardren, Traci
>
> 2004  “Where Are the Maya in Ancient Maya Archaeological Tourism? Advertising and the Appropriation of Culture.” In *Marketing Heritage: Archaeology and the Consumption of the Past*, edited by Yorke M. Rowan and Uzi Baram, 103-116. Walnut Creek, CA: Rowman and Littlefield.

AND all instances of

```
(.” )(<*>)( [0-9])
```

as in

> JOURNAL ARTICLE EXAMPLE:
>
> Cipolla, Craig N., and James Quinn
>
> 2016   “Field School Archaeology the Mohegan Way: Reflections on Twenty Years of Community-Based Research and Teaching.” *Journal of Community Archaeology & Heritage* 3 (2): 118–34.

(These journal and edited volume titles aren't always italicized properly, so I can't just search for formatting, alas.)

I would just run these two searches separately, back-to-back, and do the stuff I need separately, but when I run the first search, it might find a journal article first, see there's not an "edited by," and keep going until it finds an entry that DOES have an "edited by," which might be pages later. Alternatively, the journal article search breaks on edited volume citations, because it doesn't see the ( [0-9]) that tells it to stop.

Any advice on how I should proceed? I know nothing about VBA or regex or anything: I'm just a publishing minion trying to automate some of our most tedious tasks.

Thanks!

Comment: Unclear what exactly you are doing. Give examples of what you trying to edit, both the above examples with after and before editing. Mark with Bold the text that is found and its replacement.

Answer (score 1):

If the only problem here is matching across multiple lines try to replace `(<*>)` with `(<[!^13]@>)`. In this way this middle part won't match end of line and the search will stop.